# bootstrap token/tag with mysql database

Tags: jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap-3, tags, token

Looking to add a token/tagging system for images and videos to a site. Looking at bootstrap tag-input but have a few specs that need to work out.

1. There will be a database of tokes/tags with id assign to them
2. Ability to auto select/suggest existing tags
3. Ability to add tags that are not in the database, on the fly.
4. New tags will only be available to the person who creates them
5. Each tag for the image/video will be in a database table with it's
   own row and id assign to it. An association table of image/video id and
   tag id
6. When removing a tag, clicking on an x, it will remove only the tag
   in the association table

Kinda have an idea, but could use some extra help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a tagging system working.

I created 2 tables, First table I loaded a preset list of tags and had a user id column, which was set to zero (0). The second table was an association table with the use/account id, photo id, tag id (from the first table with list of tags).

I stared with the bootstrap token/tagging plugin/js. But only wound up using the format/css and modified it to match the site.

I used typeahead.js on the input to autofill/suggest with public and usre's tags. Used js to check if key was return to submit the tag via ajax.

The script would check to see if the supplied tag exist, if yes it would use the assign ID, if no it would add the new tag and use the new ID and assign it to the user. It would also check to see if the tag has already been assigned to the photo/video.

If it was successful in adding the new tag to the photo/video, it would return the name and ID on the new assoc. tag. Then the tag  would be created, including another  with the onclick calling the function to remove the tag.

The js function to remove the tag would delete the row in the assoc. table. If successful it would then remove the tag, if not an alert would pop up.